# Google DataFusion : HUB creation

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

How to create and host private HUB under DataFusion and how to configure DataFusion make reference to such private HUB.

Answer (score 0):

@alex:
CDAP 6.2 ([release notes](https://github.com/cdapio/cdap/releases/tag/v6.2.0)) added the ability to support multiple hubs.

You would need to configure the cdap-site property (`market.base.urls`) with list of hubs (string with `+` as delimiter) and restart CDAP. This property will be passed on to the UI which should surface the multiple hubs.

The [design doc](https://wiki.cask.co/display/CE/Support+multiple+hubs+in+CDAP) for this feature is available here for more information. We are working on documentation and this should soon be available via CDAP docs.